# What is the inverse $z^{-1}(z)$ of $z(\varphi)=e^{i\varphi}$ with $\varphi\in\Bbb N_0$?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Suppose I am given a complex number $z=x+iy\in\Bbb C$, with $\left|z\right|=1$, and I am told that $z=e^{i\varphi}$ for some integer $\varphi\in\Bbb N_0$ (the value of which is not given to me).

How do I find this integer $\varphi$ with a formula?
Is there a closed form solution for this?

Is the solution unique?

Does the solution (closed form or not) have a name?

*Clarification.* I think this translates as: How many integer radians do I need to rotate anti-clockwise along the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to get to $z$, *given* that it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "use the inversion"?

Comment: Oh I see, so you want a formula for the argument $\varphi$ of a complex number. I think that this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) should be helpful then.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero I don't think it addresses integer solutions. Did I read over it?

Comment: @Gugg: I am not sure I understand your question, but since $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$, there are actually infinite different complex numbers that you can get by plugging in integer values of $\theta$. The argument will be a value between $0$ and $2\pi$ (this is one possible range, another popular possibility is $-\pi$ to $\pi$). To get an argument in this range, just take $\theta$ modulo $2\pi$, that is - subtract $2\pi$ over and over until you get a value between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: @Gugg Yes, I don't think it addresses "integer solutions". Maybe you should try to clarify your question a bit, because in my opinion it is a little hard to understand what exactly it is that you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your last edit: "How many integer radians do I need to rotate anti-clockwise along the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to get to $z$, *given* that it can be done?"

Given that it can be done, the argument of $z$ is $\arg z = \varphi + 2\pi k$ for a unique pair of integers $\varphi$ and $k$.
(I'll leave as an exercise - why is the pair unique?)

Let's change our language in a way that'll help us understand what problem we're dealing with here. Let $G$ be the group $G = \{\left[0, 2\pi\right), +\}$ with the $+$ operation being "addition modulo $2\pi$". Notice that the neutral element here is $0$.

Your problem translates as: "Given an element $z = n\cdot1_G$, how do I recover $n$?"

Note: In an additive group, multiplying by an integer is like taking a power in a "regular" group. So the group-theoretic problem is: Given $a = b^n$, where $a, b$ are known, how do I recover $n$?

This problem is called the [discrete logarithm problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). There is no known general formula for the solution of this problem; computationally, it has been compared to the integer factorization problem (especially in how a general fast solution to this problem can break certain cryptographic systems).

Comment: I don't think the analogy with the discrete logarithm problem works here. Before talking about computational aspects, it would first need to be clarified in what form $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\varphi}$ is given. It's not clear that any answer other than "in the form of $\varphi$" is possible, and in that representation the problem is of course trivial.

Comment: @joriki: One other possibility is "Alice picks $\varphi$ and sends $e^{i \varphi}$ to Bob". But I agree - my answer is relevant to the case that $z$ just falls from the sky. More insight about where it comes from would be helpful. @Gugg?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein Many thanks, I hadn't the slightest clue where (within mathematics) to look. $\varphi$ comes from one model/theory and $e^{i\varphi}$ comes from another model/theory. I'm trying to get a grasp of the relations among them, and how good these models compare. So, both values are literally theoretical and "falling from the sky" seems appropriate. Now, the only thing perhaps missing is a suitable name and symbol for the solution, possibly one that is conventional (perhaps likely given that there's no known closed formula for it and that anyone could come up with this question).

Comment: @Yoni: I'm not sure I've made clear what I meant. The real and imaginary parts of $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ are transcendental. It's not obvious how Alice might send Bob $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ other than by sending $\phi$. Certainly sending some rational or algebraic approximation won't help, since $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ gets arbitrarily close to any given number on the unit circle infinitely often, so $\phi$ is only well-defined if you have $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$ itself, not some approximation to it. How do you send a transcendental number?

Comment: @joriki: Good point, forget transcendental - there aren't really even irrational numbers in computer science. But you could restrict yourself to, say, $\left| \varphi \right| < 2^{10000}$, calculate the $\epsilon$ such that there is a unique integer solution within $\epsilon$ of $e^{i \varphi}$ for any possible $\varphi$, and send a rational number that's within $\epsilon$ of $z$. I think the problem you get is no less hard.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be a solution for this, since the integers are countable and the unit circle has the cardinality of the continuum and is thus uncountable.

Comment: @Gugg: You need to escape the curly braces; unescaped curly braces are used for grouping, not as delimiters in $\TeX$. And yes, it would make sense to edit that into the question. While you're at it, you might want to add in which form you're given $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\varphi}$ (since apparently it's not given in the form of $\varphi$).

Comment: @Gugg: "Escape" in the context of languages that use backslashes for giving special meaning to characters means "precede by a backslash".

Comment: @Gugg: Now you escaped the vertical bar, which happens to yield a command for a double norm bar. Anyway, you shouldn't be using a vertical bar there, since it's treated as an absolute value bar and gets corresponding spacing (or lack thereof); the appropriate command for the vertical bar in the set builder notation is `\mid`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. How about: isn't there a solution for $z\in\left\{e^{i \varphi}\mid \varphi \in \Bbb N \right\}$? Should I edit that into the question?

Comment: @Gugg: See above: Yes, but you should also add what you mean by that. In the abstract, there is clearly an inverse of the map $\varphi\to\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\varphi}$ if $\varphi$ is restricted to integers. In concrete terms, however, it only makes sense to ask how to find $\varphi$ if you tell us how you have $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\varphi}$.

Comment: That is another one of your excellent points that I didn't quite see yet, even after you pointed it out. $e^{i\varphi}$ is what is used by one model and $\varphi$ is used by another model. They are both abstract.